# saving model value while using directive with isolated scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created an directive with isolated scope named `<student>`, everything is working fine am able to pass different data to my directive using isolated scope "=". But am not able to save the changes in the data.
code:

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" >
    <div layout="column" flex ng-controller="StudentController">
        <student operation="productadd"></student>

        <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">click</button>
       <div style="float:left;background:#ccc;">

           <!--<student operation="productmodify"></student>-->
       </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngMaterial']);

mainApp.controller('StudentController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {



    $scope.productadd = {};



    $scope.productadd.colors = ['#a55466', '#8298a6', '#586a75', '#af1e2c', '#b3995d', '#7fc7af',
            '#afb4bb', '#b9adad', '#899a9f', '#7d7d7d', '#525252', '#636c6f',
            '#347d7b', '#b1b1b1', '#53748c', '#927f92', '#695769', '#a07c7c', '#6f7d86',
            '#94b1c4', '#24122a', '#6c6169', '#6d5656', '#d19898', '#ac7c7c', '#aaaaaa',
            '#bbcccc', '#999999', '#ccbbbb', '#779999', '#cdc1c5', '#8b8386'];

    $scope.productadd.uomList = ['oz1', 'mm2', 'meter3'];

    $scope.productadd.merchList = ['hand', 'tray', 'case', 'basket'];

    $scope.productadd.nameList = ['Unit', 'Case', 'TRAY', 'Pallet 4 layers', 'Half Pallet 3 layers', ' Half Pallet 4 layers', ' Cut Case 24', 'Pallet 3 layers', 'Cut Case 12'];

    $scope.productadd.orientationList = ['Front End', 'Front Side', 'Side End', 'Side Front', 'End Front', 'End Side'];

    $scope.productadd.distributerTypeList = ['WHS', 'DSP', 'DSB', 'DSA', 'DSS', 'DSD'];



    $scope.productmodify = {};



    $scope.productmodify.colors = ['#a55466', '#8298a6'];

    $scope.productmodify.uomList = ['oz', 'mm', 'meter'];

    $scope.productmodify.merchList = ['hand', 'tray', 'case', 'basket'];

    $scope.productmodify.nameList = ['Unit', 'Case', 'TRAY', 'Pallet 4 layers', 'Half Pallet 3 layers', ' Half Pallet 4 layers', ' Cut Case 24', 'Pallet 3 layers', 'Cut Case 12'];

    $scope.productmodify.orientationList = ['Front End', 'Front Side', 'Side End', 'Side Front', 'End Front', 'End Side'];

    $scope.productmodify.distributerTypeList = ['WHS', 'DSP', 'DSB', 'DSA', 'DSS', 'DSD'];





    $scope.submit = function () {

        console.log($scope.product);
    }


}]);

mainApp.directive('student', function () {

    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl:'temp.html',

    scope: {
        productedit: "=operation"
    },


    }


});
```

[examplecode](http://plnkr.co/edit/1GwItiesZWMHiKk0T1Hp?p=preview)

I have added an submit and am trying to save my model named product. But am getting undefined.

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: add some related code with plunkr/fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have currently have your html structure, you have placed your submit form button outside the directive template. For solving this issue, basically you are just passing the value of `dropdowns`. So i'd suggest you to pass the value of `product` object which would be initially `{}` & that will be modified by the directive template.

**HTML**

```
<student operation="productadd" product="product"></student>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.product = {}; //initially blank, filled up by directive.
```

**Directive**

```
mainApp.directive('student', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'temp.html',

    scope: {
      productedit: "=operation",
      product: '=' //pass product object here
    },
  }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4FnOfK2kgShJJ5TD045H?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  console.log($scope.product);
};
```

It logs an undefined scope property so it will never save any changes anywhere

```
mainApp.directive('student', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'temp.html',
    scope: {
      productedit: "=operation"
    },
    }
});
```

1. Should not have , after scope property (it's the last property on that object),
2. Where is your controller/link function?
3. You should move productadd to a service.